# FatalThrowableError in web.php

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

```
FatalThrowableError in web.php line 38:    
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or '{' or '$'
```

An error encountered when I tried to access a view from a controller. controller.

My routes:

```
Route::group(['middleware' -> ['web']], function() {
    Route::resource('company', 'CompanyController');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using `->` instead of `=>`. It should be:

```
['middleware' => ['web']]
```

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Comment: That's a quick response. Thanks :D Though I encountered another error after solving that one.  `NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161:`

Comment: It means this problem was fixed but you've got another error in the code.